# Method for solving complicated integrals

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Is there a general method, some sort of algorithm, for evaluating integrals?
I find myself having trouble knowing what method I am supposed to use at what point.

For example, how does one go about something like $$\int\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}dx$$ or $$\int\frac{e^x +1}{e^x - 1}dx$$

What am I looking for when I am not sure how to tackle a complex integral?

Comment: What methods do you know already? Substitution and partial integration?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange.You will get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you ask detailed questions and show your work. The only way to learn what to try when integrating is to practice lots of integrals. It's like any other sport.

Comment: Yeah I know subs, and partial integration aswell as rules regarding integrating sin/cos that are to a higher power than 2 multiplied by each other

Comment: All rational functions (division of polynomials) have a indefinite integral that can be stated in "closed form", that is, in terms of elementary functions. The second integral can be transformed in a rational after the change of variable $e^x=y$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no general method for evaluating an arbitrary integral. Unlike differentiation, the reverse operation isn't algorithmic. So calling it the integral *calculus* is, properly speaking, a misnomer, for it's not a calculus like differentiation, or elementary arithmetic, say.

So, the thing about evaluating integrals is practice, experience and ingenuity. You make clever substitutions, educated guesses, etc. This, again, only emerges by much practice.

Comment: well, it is not clear what means "algorithmic", I mean, I guess what you want to says but I dont know if this concept can be formalized properly.

Comment: @Allawonder Through doing AP Calc I think you are quite right. From my experience, even very similar integrals such as those of $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$, $\frac{1}{x^3+1}$ and $\frac{1}{x^4+1}$ are very different. Also, I think that the vast majority integrals cannot be evaluated simply, so for some integrals merely proving that they can be expressed simply is quite difficult.

Comment: The very first claim is not entirely true - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Last I checked, there's a difference between elementary and arbitrary. And even the algorithm above, or any other special one, doesn't do what the OP wanted. Perhaps the word algorithm doesn't describe the problematic well. Unlike in differentiation, or arithmetic addition, there's no step by step procedure leading from first principles to the solution. Integration involves first guessing or remembering a derivative, and that is not a first principle in the sense wanted, namely a basic operation like computing a difference, a ratio of differences, and taking limits of ratios...

Comment: @Allawonder: agreed, I just wanted to stress that for practical purposes, *there is* an algorithmic way. With a lot of effort it can be probably extended in order to deal with a lot of hypergeometric functions. Given the recent breakthroughs in artificial intelligence, I won't take out from the table the chance, in a forthcoming future, to teach microprocessors how to be skilled integrators. On the human side it is a process which requires a lot of time and experience, on the CPU side it might require just a few days, at most.

Comment: Still you gloss over the point that by algorithmic, I meant, as I explained above, 'derivable from first principles', and not anything about what computers can do, so to say. The OP is clearly concerned about whether, on the human level, there are methods that originate from elementary ones that may allow us to extract an antiderivative. There are none, and can never be. Strictly speaking, there's no calculus for finding so-called indefinite integrals.

Comment: Wow thank you for all the useful explanations, you guys helpend me alot! I figured there is no set way but I am often unsure wether I am supposed to use one method or another one. Some gross rules regarding inverse trig And e^x^another number multiplications are the once that I struggle the most how to start the problem once I figure out the initial u-sub or another method it seems to be easier but its the first step thats 90% of the work

Answer (score 0):

For the first you need to write the following.$$\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}=\frac{x^3+x-x}{x^2+1}=x-\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$ because you know that $$\left(\ln(x^2+1)\right)'=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}.$$
For the second you need to write the following.
$$\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}=\frac{2e^x-e^x+1}{e^x-1}=\frac{2e^x}{e^x-1}-1$$ because you know that
$$\left(\ln|e^x-1|\right)'=\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}.$$

Comment: "because you know that" is followed by an equality that may not be immediately obvious or deducible from someone who is asking "Is there a general method, some sort of algorithm, for evaluating integrals?" I would personally make note of a u-substitution $u=e^x$.